# Cumulocity: storing docker images is not supported in 'none' microservice provider

Tags: docker, microservices, cumulocity

I'm trying to create a microservice for Cumulocity.
Nevertheless, trying both java,python i get the same error as result.

> Cumulocity: storing docker images is not supported in 'none'
>   microservice provider/Unprocessable Entity

Does anyone faced the same problem and could give me any suggestion?

Comment: Can you share what you are actually doing (like e.g. request) that is returning you this error

Comment: Hi @TyrManuZ thank you for you answer. What I'm doing is following the guide here ( https://cumulocity.com/guides/microservice-sdk/java ) and in particular applyinf the step "Deployment - Step 2". When I throw the 
POST {URL}/application/applications/{APPLICATION_ID}/binaries I'm having as answer the "error" I posted

Comment: Try to update your question as good as you can adding all information. HTTP response code, structure of the zip you are uploading, content of the manifest file. if you can post full requests/response. The less information you share the more difficult it is to help you and nobody will invest the time. Keep in mind that also others hopefully can use your problem and the solution in order to solve their problems